# Is an empty array created using alloc and init automatically set to nil?

Tags: objective-c

Just a simple question, I hope.

When creating an array using alloc and init, i.e. without specifying 'initWith...' or preloading it with objects, is that array automatically set to nil?

For example:

```
NSMutableArray *buffetItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And would the same apply when you use the class method `array`?

```
NSMutableArray *buffetItems = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: The array is set to "empty".

Comment: I was having trouble visualising how exactly 'empty' is represented. Count = zero seems to be it.

Comment: You can have a shelf with all your books on it; you can have a shelf which doesn't contain any books; you can have a wall with no shelf. You can have an array that has strings in it; you can have an array which doesn't contain any objects; you can have an array variable with no array.

Comment: 'array variable with no array': awesome way of encapsulating it. Thanks a ton Josh! P.S I like the carrick bend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

`nil` and the empty array are completely different things in Objective-C, unlike, say Lisp.

`nil` is (for all intents and purposes) an opaque value that indicates the absence of any value in a variable. This is fundamentally semantically different than the absence of elements in an array.

Comment: So when you create an array with alloc and init, what value is it initialised to? Or is it simply allocated a memory address?

Comment: @shinnyWhack: the empty array.

Comment: @shinnyWhack: the array with no elements in. It.

Comment: How is that represented? By 0?

Comment: No. An array can have any number of elements, including none.

Comment: When it is empty,  is it initialized to zero, or what does the init do exactly?

Comment: Sets the length of the array to zero, and allocates no memory for elements.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. It is simply an array that exists as it has been allocated memory, and it is initialised to have a count of zero? But it has no value. And it is not nil. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and no. It has a value - that value is the empty array. Think of it this way: nil is having nothing, and the empty array is having an empty box. You still have *something*, it just doesn't have anything in it.

Comment: Thanks a mil, totally get it now. Helps for everything going foward. Cheers mate!

Comment: Awesome! So glad I could help. Good luck with all your programming!